# What is the meaning of i.to_s in Ruby?

Tags: ruby

I want to understand a piece of code I found in Google:

```
i.to_s
```

In the above code `i` is an integer. As per my understanding `i` is being converted into a string. Is that true?

Comment: You guess is right, `to_s` method returns string representation of an object (in that case of number `i`). But for that kind of questions I'd suggest using Ruby [documentation](http://www.ruby-doc.org/). You can find documentation for every method from standard library there.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Better to say that this is an expression returning the string representation of the integer `i`.  The integer itself doesn't change. #pedantic.

In irb

```
>> 54.to_s
=> "54"
>> 4598734598734597345937423647234.to_s
=> "4598734598734597345937423647234"
>> i = 7
=> 7
>> i.to_s
=> "7"
>> i
=> 7
```

Answer (score 7):

As noted in the other answers, calling .to_s on an integer will return the string representation of that integer.

```
9.class         #=>  Fixnum
9.to_s          #=>  "9"
9.to_s.class    #=>  String
```

But you can also pass an argument to .to_s to change it from the default Base = 10 to anything from Base 2 to Base 36. Here is the documentation: [Fixnum to_s](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Fixnum.html#method-i-to_s). So, for example, if you wanted to convert the number 1024 to it's equivalent in binary (aka Base 2, which uses only "1" and "0" to represent any number), you could do:

```
1024.to_s(2)    #=> "10000000000"
```

Converting to Base 36 can be useful when you want to generate random combinations of letters and numbers, since it counts using every number from 0 to 9 and then every letter from a to z. [Base 36 explanation on Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Base_36). For example, the following code will give you a random string of letters and numbers of length 1 to 3 characters long (change the 3 to whatever maximum string length you want, which increases the possible combinations):

```
rand(36**3).to_s(36)
```

To better understand how the numbers are written in the different base systems, put this code into irb, changing out the 36 in the parenthesis for the base system you want to learn about. The resulting printout will count from 0 to 35 in which ever base system you chose

```
36.times {|i| puts i.to_s(36)}
```

Answer (score 2):

That is correct. `to_s` converts any object to a string, in this case (probably) an integer, since the variable is called `i`.